# Nested analytic functions in Oracle

Tags: oracle, analytic-functions

Can we use nested analytic function within analytic function? We can use another analytic function within expression or not?

Please provide me one example.

Comment: what do you mean by expression buddy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot nest analytic functions.  From the [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#SQLRF51196):

> You cannot nest analytic functions by specifying any analytic function
>   in any part of the analytic_clause. However, you can specify an
>   analytic function in a subquery and compute another analytic function
>   over it.

For example:

```
SQL> select sum(count(*) over ()) over () from dual;
select sum(count(*) over ()) over () from dual
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-30483: window  functions are not allowed here
```